# "file://" breaks href in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

So I'm using CKEditor (4.4.7) through a Redmine plugin for my project.  I've spent 2 whole days now searching this issue and have tried a bunch of things to no avail, so I am tapping out and asking for help.  What is happening is that when I attempt to use the "file://" syntax for a link in the editor, it appears to break the HTML href operation.

This is what I have written:

```
<a href="file://\\mydrive\root">My Drive Link</a>
```

This is what the CKEditor ends up generating for my page:

```
<a>My Drive Link</a>
```

If I replace the "file://" with say "http://", then it works fine:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
```

Result:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
```

Just to make sure I am writing this correctly, using Chrome's developer tool, I change the line of HTML on my page with exactly what I have written and the link now works beautifully.  It seems CKEditor doesn't know what to do with the "file://" part.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

I have tried a number of customization tricks with the editor config file to force the "< a>" to have an 'href', but nothing has worked so far.